# Prevent the scrapy spider from crawling one part of the website too long

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I have built a scrapy spider that crawls through all the internal links within a website. However, when I run the spider, there are some websites whose large portion of websites have little to do with the contents of the websites. For example, one website runs Jenkins, and my spider spends disportionately large amount of time exploring these pages that are not relevant to the website at all.

One way would be to make a blacklist and add some paths such as Jenkins to it, but I was wondering if there is a better way of handling this.

```
class MappingItem(dict, BaseItem):
    pass

class WebsiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Website"

    def __init__(self):
        item = MappingItem()
        self.loader = ItemLoader(item)
        self.filter_urls = list()

    def start_requests(self):
        filename = "filename.csv"
        try:
            with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
                reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                header = next(reader)
                for row in reader:
                    seed_url = row[1].strip()
                    base_url = urlparse(seed_url).netloc
                    self.filter_urls.append(base_url)
                    request = Request(seed_url, callback=self.parse_seed)
                    request.meta['base_url'] = base_url

                    yield request
        except IOError:
            raise CloseSpider("A list of websites are needed")

    def parse_seed(self, response):
        base_url = response.meta['base_url']
        # handle external redirect while still allowing internal redirect
        if urlparse(response.url).netloc != base_url:
            return
        external_le = LinkExtractor(deny_domains=base_url)
        external_links = external_le.extract_links(response)
        for external_link in external_links:
            if urlparse(external_link.url).netloc in self.filter_urls:
                self.loader.add_value(base_url, external_link.url)

        internal_le = LinkExtractor(allow_domains=base_url)
        internal_links = internal_le.extract_links(response)

        for internal_link in internal_links:
            request = Request(internal_link.url, callback=self.parse_seed)
            request.meta['base_url'] = base_url
            request.meta['dont_redirect'] = True
            yield request
```

Comment: Are you using Link Extractors? Showing the relevant part of your spider code might help to help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the Link Extractor's [`deny_domains`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor) argument is something for you to use for the "blacklist" of domains not to follow:

> `deny_domains` (str or list) – a single value or a list of strings
>   containing domains which won’t be considered for extracting the links

Comment: This seems to be one solution, but the problem is that even after I face this "sinkhole" where my spider spends most of the time, I would have to manually add in all the forms of sinkholes.

Comment: One way I thought of circumventing this was by limiting the number of visits you can make on a particular paths, but the problem is that there might be too many false positive sinkholes when they are solid contents. For example, if the spider spends thousands of requests on `www.website.com/jenkins/`, then it should terminate, but if `www.website.com/articles/' and there are thousands of articles, the spider should send requests since they are relevant materials. I guess what I need to do is find some kind of a pattern that can distinguish between useful and useless webpages.

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP got it. You should probably build some custom logic around it - for instance, have a domain-priority mapping that would define the relevance of a domain and a counter dict (`defaultdict(int)` I suppose) that you would use to count the number of visits per-domain. Then you can use some relevance to request count rule to determine if you need to stop crawling a specific domain. It all sounds like you need a custom middleware...just a feeling.